# What is the best way to create a color palette for a presentation or so?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign

I need to create a professional color palette for my guideline working on  InDesign, but i am not sure how or what are the steps!

Comment: Hi Amd, thanks for your question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Is the question related to the "profesional", "the color palete" or how to include it on an indesign project?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a good resource or tool to help build a palette/color scheme around colors I select?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/352/is-there-a-good-resource-or-tool-to-help-build-a-palette-color-scheme-around-col)

Answer (score 2):

If this is for web design I would suggest you look into [Style Tiles](http://styletil.es/):

Example:

[image]

Also [StyleTiles](https://github.com/AdyGould/StyleTiles)

If this is for print you could still create something similar to a style tile but more tailored to your preferences.  I would also encourage learning how to save color palettes as `.ase` formats.

Ideally the best approach is to automate your workflow.  If you offer or know that a client is going to want color callouts, fonts, etc. etc. then you should consider creating templates for this.  Even if you're in web or print InDesign would be the best option since you could create a basic template to bring in and update it with what you're going to use in your project.

Since this question is very lacking also reference:

- [Working with color palettes](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20435/working-with-color-palettes)
- [How to pick large color palettes?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20435/working-with-color-palettes)
- [A simple search in the top right](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=color%20palettes)

---

comment:

If you have images you need to pull color from bring it into Photoshop and use the color picker to pull colors and browse the many questions we have on where to build color palettes.

---

Per the comment below the answer using Adobe Kuler:

If you are on Kuler you need to sign into it to be able to save the color palette:

[image]

Comment: actually! i dont know the real steps from where should i start or what should i use?! my images in indesign is a guideline for a visual merchandiser so it's an images for a store and mannequins!

Answer (score 0):

Check out Kuler by Adobe. https://color.adobe.com/

There are also already submitted palettes you can explore.

Comment: the problem is how to drag the pallet to the guideline!

Comment: ok i did a screenshot

Comment: @AmdEddieNasri if you look at my edit you will see where I addressed your comment